# SCSS - how to represent

Tags: sass, nested-class

The nested class in CSS

```
.wrapper .widecolumn {
    width: 983px;
}
```

could be repersented in SCSS as

```
.wrapper {
    .widecolumn {
        width: 983px;
    }
}
```

but how to represent this?:

```
.wrapper.widecolumn {
    width: 983px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wrapper.widecolumn {
    width: 983px;
}
```

is fine (assuming here that wrapper is an example tag). If you're just concerned about nesting, use & like so:

```
wrapper {
    &.widecolumn {
        width: 983px;
    }
}
```

The & represents the parent object, so you can also do clever things like

```
wrapper {
    &.widecolumn {
        width: 983px;
    }
    &:hover {
        color: red;
    }
    body.mycoolclass & {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last one is optimal for huge stylesheets if you want to lose the overview because it completely messes up your nesting...

Comment: I use it sometimes with modernizr's HTML-tag classes, to allow options for redneck browsers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the point before wrapper, so ".wrapper"

Answer (score -3):

You can do Also

```css
.wrapper {
    
  &__widecolumn {
        width: 983px;
    }
  
}
```

When you will do that then you can simply use This just like that :

```html
<div class="wrapper__widecolumn">

  <!-- This Column will be 983px -->

  
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what's being asked here at all.